# Why can't I call OrderBy in a class that extends List?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, inheritance, extension-methods

I have a class, `Deck`, that contains a method called `Shuffle`.

I'm working on refactoring `Deck` to extend `List<Card>`, rather than having `List<Card> Cards` as a property. However, while `Cards.OrderBy (a => Guid.NewGuid ())` worked, `OrderBy (a => Guid.NewGuid ())` does not:

`Error CS0103: The name 'OrderBy' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)`

Why does this not work?

Comment: To understand why everyone is insisting you shouldn't inherit from `List<T>`, have a look at this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/26/474010.aspx   In reality, while you're missing a few things (e.g. collection-modified notifications) by inheriting from `List<T>`, if you're not using your inheriting class in a public API, it's totally up to you if you want to use `List<T>` as your base class.  Not inheriting from `List<T>` is a recommendation, not a hard-and-fast rule.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @Kyralessa. The recommendation seems like a good one. Inheriting List<T> was a bad idea in the first place, and the fact that List<T> wasn't designed to be inherit just makes it an even worse idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `this` to the front of `OrderBy` as in

```
this.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid()); // a random ordering
```

`OrderBy` is an extension method on `IEnumerable<T>` and is not a public method on `List<T>`. If you type `OrderBy` with no context the compiler will look for an instance or static method named `OrderBy`. It is only if you prefix `OrderBy` with an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` will the compiler find `OrderBy`. As `Deck : List<Card>` and `List<Card> : IEnumerable<Card>`, using the keyword `this` (a reference to the current instance) will give the compiler the context it needs to locate the method `Enumerable.OrderBy`.

It is considered [bad practice to inherit from `List<T>` in a public API](http://blogs.msdn.com/kcwalina/archive/2005/09/26/474010.aspx). First, `List<T>` was not designed for inheritance and probably should have been `sealed`; too late for that now. In general, you should favor composition over inheritance when using framework classes.

Comment: Correction: It's considered bad practice to inherit from `List<T>` *in a public API*.  If the inheriting class isn't part of a public API, then it's not a problem.

Comment: +1 Thank you for posting that last paragraph! So often people gloss over that point. I recommend Collection<T> or ObservableCollection<T>.

Answer (score 3):

`OrderBy` is an extension method, so it can only be used with a qualifier of type `IEnumerable<T>`.

You need to write `this.OrderBy`.  (`this` is a qualifier of type `Deck`, which indirectly inherits `IEnumerable<Card>`)

Note that `OrderBy` is not an in-place sort; if you want to sort the existing instance, call `Sort((a, b) => 2 - 2 * rand.Next(0, 1))` where `rand` is an instance of the `Random` class.

---

**Note**: It is [bad practice to inherit `List<T>`](http://blogs.msdn.com/fxcop/archive/2006/04/27/585476.aspx).  Instead, you should inherit [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

OrderBy is not a method on `List<T>` - rather, it's defined as an extension method [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx).

Because it's not a method of the class, you need to make the compiler see this.  You can do that by calling:

this.OrderBy(a => Guid.NewGuid());

However, I recommend rethinking your approach here.  Subclassing `List<T>` is a bad idea - it's much better to implement `IList<T>` by encapsulating your `List<T>` instance.  `List<T>` should be an implementation detail, and not part of the API itself.

Comment: I think you're right (about re-thinking my approach). I had noticed that I was re-implementing several methods/properties in `List`, such as `Count`. But I don't want to bring in all the methods that I *don't* need along with those that I do. It's pretty simple to wrap the methods that I do need in new methods.