# Web API ArgumentNullException was unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to implement error handling in my WebAPI and I have `ErrorController.cs` with the following code:

```
public class ErrorController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet, HttpPost, HttpPut, HttpDelete, HttpHead, HttpOptions, AcceptVerbs("PATCH")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Handle404()
    {
        var responseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        responseMessage.ReasonPhrase = "The requested resource is not found";
        return Request.CreateResponse(new { error = "The requested resource is not found" });
    }
}
```

I make an API call like this:

```
http://localhost:46151/api/TData?ROOM=ABC&DOB_GT=01-SEP-05&DOB_LT=30-DEC-06&STATUS_TYPE=CMT
```

In order to force an error to occur I tried mispelling one of the query parameters (from `DOB_LT` to `DO_LT`) to check how errors are being handled -- like this:

`http://localhost:46151/api/TData?ROOM=ABC&DOB_GT=01-SEP-05&DO_LT=30-DEC-06&STATUS_TYPE=CMT`

The debugger breaks in ErrorController as shown in the image below:

[image]

Tried try Catch block like

```
        catch (Exception ex)
         {
             var returnObj = new { error = ex.Message };
             var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, returnObj, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
             ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
             if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=error.json", out contentDisposition))
             {
                 response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
             }
             return response;
         }
```

Comment: Take a good look at the following post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139621/how-do-i-return-notfound-ihttpactionresult-with-an-error-message-or-exception -- especially the one-line solution presented by @AnthonyF

Comment: @DavidTansey Do I use `return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Foo does not exist.");` in my catch block?

Comment: I just the found the sample that you are probably working from -- I hope I have not mislead you.  More info when I get a closer look at the sample.

Comment: Yes from another controller. What I am trying to do is the current API returns query result in JSON.  Likewise I want to return the error messages or exception as JSON like `{"error":" Exception Message"}. I tried using the try catch block in the controller as I  edited in my question but this is not working

Comment: @DavidTansey Yes please help out with this. I will have to return the exception in JSON

Comment: @trx Why don't you use exception filter for that?