# Acceptable return options for IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am looking for, but not finding, a list of all acceptable return options for IHttpActionResult. I know of these two:

- OK(object)
- NotFound()

Are there more? And where are they documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are tons:

See: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results(v=vs.118).aspx

This one is my favorite because you can put custom return codes in it e.g.: `NoContent 204`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.results.statuscoderesult(v=vs.118).aspx

Example:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoIt()
{
     return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
}
```

Basically all http error codes are supported, I would advise to stick with them for compliance reasons.

Comment: marked as answer because of the example. Thanks!

Comment: If you want something custom, it's worth checking out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20139621/how-do-i-return-notfound-ihttpactionresult-with-an-error-message-or-exception

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 2):

All of those methods are implemented by `ApiController`, the base class for your Web API controllers.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.apicontroller(v=vs.118).aspx

Every method on that page with a description that starts with "Creates a" is such a method.

Comment: Score for the `Creates a` remark, it makes life easier :-)